# Laravel deleting method

Tags: php, laravel-5, sql-delete

I have written the code below in my controller to delete a comment :

```
public function destroy($ID)
{
    $post = Comment::find($ID);
    $post->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And this is my Route :

```
Route::delete('/deleteComment/{ID}', 'CommentController@destroy');
```

And this is my form :

```
<form action="{{ url('/deleteComment/'.$comment->ID) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">حذف کردن</button>
</form>
```

But When I click the button, It doesn't delete anything ...
I appreciate any response ...

Comment: is there any error?, can you post the error

Comment: No, There is no error ..., It just redirect back to my page ...

Comment: try doing dd($post); before $post->delete(); just to check whether you are getting post or not

Comment: I tried that & showed me the post ...

Comment: Then you can try destroy method of Laravel like this $post->destroy($ID);

Comment: I tried that, But it didn't delete !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102149/discussion-between-akshay-khale-and-ali).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `method="post"` with `method="delete"` and try again in your form:

```
<form action="{{ url('/deleteComment/'.$comment->ID) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">حذف کردن</button>
</form>
```